# Overriding a method with generic exception and generic type at the same time

Tags: java, generics

I'm having some trouble overriding a method declared in a interface, which uses a generic parameter for its exception and a generic as one of its arguments. To illustrate, I wrote the following code interface & class

```java
package test;

import java.lang.IllegalArgumentException;
import java.util.List;

interface Interfaz {

    <ARGUMENT_EXCEPTION extends IllegalArgumentException> String metodoA(String[] params) throws ARGUMENT_EXCEPTION;

    <ARGUMENT_EXCEPTION extends IllegalArgumentException> String metodoB(List<String> params) throws ARGUMENT_EXCEPTION;

    <ARGUMENT_EXCEPTION extends IllegalArgumentException> String metodoC(List<String> params) throws ARGUMENT_EXCEPTION;

}

class Implementadora implements Interfaz {
        //This overrides metodoA correctly
        @Override
    public String metodoA(String[] params) throws IllegalArgumentException {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("ex");
        }

    //This one won't override metodoB, however
    @Override
    public String metodoB(List<String> params) throws IllegalArgumentException {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("ex");
        }

    //Ugly workaround (with unchecked cast)
    @Override
    public <ARGUMENT_EXCEPTION extends IllegalArgumentException> String metodoC(List<String> params) throws ARGUMENT_EXCEPTION {
                throw (ARGUMENT_EXCEPTION)new IllegalArgumentException("ex");
        }
}
```

Running this through javac, I get

```
Line: 14
Implementadora is not abstract and does not override abstract method metodoB(java.util.List) in Interfaz

Line: 23
name clash: metodoB(java.util.List) in Implementadora and metodoB(java.util.List) in Interfaz have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other

Line: 22
method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
```

Notice that, in the interface, the only difference between `metodoA` and `metodoB` is in their arguments.

Why `Implementadora`'s `metodoB()` doesn't override `Interfaz`'s `metodoB()`, but overriding `metodoA()` the same way works?

Comment: Uh.  `<ARGUMENT_EXCEPTION extends IllegalArgumentException>` doesn't mean it throws _some_ subtype of `IllegalArgumentException`, but rather, it means that the _user of the method can specify_ a subtype of `IllegalArgumentException` to be thrown.  This is not the case.

Comment: Why not declare the interface methods just to throw IllegalArgumentException? I'm struggling to see the value of generics for that.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot expect Strings to be returned in methodA and methodB look at your interface here is a version that compiles

```
class Implementadora implements Interfaz {

@Override
public <ARGUMENT_EXCEPTION extends IllegalArgumentException> String metodoA(String[] params)
        throws ARGUMENT_EXCEPTION {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public <ARGUMENT_EXCEPTION extends IllegalArgumentException> String metodoB(List<String> params)
        throws ARGUMENT_EXCEPTION {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public <ARGUMENT_EXCEPTION extends IllegalArgumentException> String metodoC(List<String> params)
        throws ARGUMENT_EXCEPTION {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
    //This overrides metodoA correctly
```

}